# Kernel module crashes when reading memory

Tags: memory

If I know the physical memory of data, because it was placed there by a memory mapped peripheral, how do I access it in a kernel module? My first instinct is to make a pointer

```
int * addr;
```

and assign it

```
addr = 0x________;
```

then read it

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%d\n",*addr);
```

but trying this makes the module crash. What's the appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow access to memory in a kernel module?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296906/how-to-allow-access-to-memory-in-a-kernel-module)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up a kernel virtual address mapping for the location e.g.

> `addr = ioremap_nocache(0x________, <size_in_bytes>);`